# UNIX: passing arguments to a shell function

Tags: function, shell, unix

I have users that print files to selected printers.
Instead of creating one function for each printer I would like to have just one and passing the files to print and the wanted printer.
The following code does not work, of course. 
Can anyone point me to the correct solution?

```
list2=`ls /spooldocs/sch/sch* |sort`
Print $list2 $printer2

Print(){
  for job in $1 ; do
    if [[ $job == *503374*.pcl ]]; then
      lp -d$2 $job
      lp -d$2 $job
    fi
    lp -d$2 $job
    lp -d$2 $job
    lp -d$2 $job
    lp -d$2 $job
  done
}
```

Comment: You need to define shell functions *before* you use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `shift` to move positional arguments to the left. You can iterate over the positional arguments with `for var; do ... ; done`:

```
#!/bin/sh

Print () {
   printer=$1
   shift
   for job; do
     echo lp "-d$printer" "$job"
   done
}

Print laserjet foo bar baz
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./x.sh
lp -dlaserjet foo
lp -dlaserjet bar
lp -dlaserjet baz
```

Comment: I also found that simply calling Print "$list2" $printer2 works (added "")